# size of each element of a struct array in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

First, I have a struct here:

```
//Space to store the results for analysis map
struct Analysis analysis_space[32];
```

Each element of analysis_space array is for one file to store the results by some calculations;

So, my question is

If I want to get the size of each one of analysis_space,

It should be `sizeof(analysis_space[0])` which returns the size of each element.

And `sizeof(analysis_space)` returns the whole array size?

Additional question:

Since analysis_space is an array, I suppose to initialize it before I store results into it?

Something like: `analysis_space[0] = '\0'` ?

Comment: Yes. Is that all?

Comment: ... and use `(sizeof analysis_space / sizeof analysis_space[0])` for the element count. `()` not needed after `sizeof` when item is an object.

Comment: @chux I find it more readable with `()`...

Comment: Also:  `sizeof` returns type `size_t`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed. As you know brackets are needed for a type but not for a variable, but a statement like `ptr = malloc(elements * sizeof * ptr);` is more readable as `ptr = malloc(elements * sizeof(*ptr));` However I have seen complaints that "`sizeof` is not a function."

Comment: @WeatherVane: You mean parentheses (`()`)? Brackets are square (`[]`).

Comment: @EugeneSh.How about the additional question. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @Olaf so you spotted my subtext, well done! As we say "if the hat fits, wear it".

Comment: @Patrick No. But come on. Ask a real question, not the yes/no ones...

Comment: @chux: More generally, the operand of `sizeof` can be either a parenthesized type name or an *expression* (not just an object). (Specifically a *unary-expression*.) As for the parentheses, I personally find `sizeof foo` clearer than `sizeof(foo)`, precisely because `sizeof` is an operator (and a keyword), not a function. It's similar to using `return foo;` rather than `return(foo);`. It's not a function call, so it shouldn't look like a function call. OTOH, `sizeof (foo)` is perfectly legal; `(foo)` is a parenthesized expression.

Comment: @WeatherVane: To be honest: I did not (not really good at that). There's just enough confusion about those names, so I wanted to state that clear. But maybe that's mostly a problem of us non-native speakers.

Comment: @Olaf: These `(` `)` are very commonly called "brackets" in UK English. It's best to show the actual characters where there might be any confusion, or to refer to "square brackets" and "curly braces".

Comment: `analysis_space[0] = '\0'` isn't going to compile, since `analysis_space[0]` is of type `struct Analysis`, not some scalar type. There's no need to initialize the array before storing results in it, as long as you're careful not to read elements that haven't had values assigned to them.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker I find the word "parentheses" and its singular form rather difficult to spell, so replacing it with "brackets" in most cases :)

Comment: @KeithThompson: As most times for C questions, I refered to the C standard. But agreed, that is EN_US. OTOH, I never saw something different for "parentheses" than those round things `()`. The confusion is more - as you wrote - about the other two (three if we add the angular whatevers `<>` of C++.

Comment: There is a definite difference in opinion. Similarly if I have an expression which computes a boolean value to be returned by a function (or assigned to a variable) I will use brackets for clarity, although redundant.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, I think "parentheses" is unambiguous. `<` and `>` (when used in pairs rather than as less-than and greater-than operators, or half of a shift operator) are commonly called "angle brackets".

Comment: Well, German has actually one word for all ("Klammern"), so we indeed **have to** qualify them anyway. But I got used to the english terms (wonder how that happended ... :-)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Perhaps "parens" would be easier?

Comment: @KeithThompson: "Paren**t**s"? ;-) Maybe that is some close-to-false friend thing? I also have some words I have to think twice.

Comment: @Olaf: No, "parens". It's a common abbreviation for "parentheses". (I saw the smiley, but I'm taking the question seriously anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Hmm, thanks; I was never sure if that is commonly accepted or more of a "slang". As a student I once (long time ago) got a harsh comment for using "nibble" in a FPGA-documentation (yes, I know since long time that Dr. Ing. was wrong). Since then I'm careful, if I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Patrick your gentle reminder about the second question, initialising a `struct`. Your idea `analysis_space[0] = '\0';` is the wrong type. I suggest `struct Analysis analysis_space[32] = {0};`

Comment: the answer to your last question is 'no', you can use it directly. People are showing you how to set it to empty, but you dont need to do that before you can set it to a valid entry

Answer (score 0):

> ... to get the size of each one of `analysis_space`, It should be `sizeof(analysis_space[0])` which returns the size of each element.

`sizeof(analysis_space[0])` returns the value of the `char` size of `analysis_space[0]`.  The type returned is `size_t` and the matching `printf()` specifier is `"%zu"`, `"%zX"` and others.  When using the `sizeof` operator, code needs to use `()` with types.  `()` are optional with objects.

```
printf("One element size %zu\n", sizeof analysis_space[0]);
```

> And `sizeof(analysis_space)` returns the whole array size?

Yes,

```
printf("Array size %zu\n", sizeof analysis_space);
```

> I suppose to initialize it before I store results into it? Something like: `analysis_space[0] = '\0'` ?

`analysis_space[0] = '\0'` is an assignment, not initialization.  Further, `struct Analysis` expects a structure assignment/initialization, not scalar.  Initialization is not required before *writing*
 to it. [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378746/size-of-each-element-of-a-struct-array-in-c?noredirect=1#comment66087125_39378746)

```
struct Analysis {
   int a;
   double b;
};

// Sample initialization
struct Analysis analysis_space[32] = { 
    {0, 0.0}, {1, 1.0} , {2, 2.0} }; // remainder zero initialized.
```

To compute the array element count:

```
// the type of the quotient is size_t
#define analysis_space_N (sizeof analysis_space / sizeof analysis_space[0])
```